# How to do In R a loop that calculate mean and median of rows and add it in a data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a data frame with the subjects in the rows and variables in the coloumn, the problem is that there are 40 rows per subjects (because each subjects had 40 trials), so not each rows correspond to each subject.

I want to have a new data frame containing one subjects per row and in the coloumn the mean and the median of some variables.

Unfortunately I'm relatively new to R and to programming languages in genereal in the sense that I never manage a for loop to work, and I guess here I need someting similar.

Can someone suggest some ways to do it?

Here is my data.

```
    Subject Trial         File    Int   Target    Synchrony     corr_ans Risposta ACC       RT
8          1     8   sinc2_lab579.wmv ASD   sinc        si              1        5     1       1418
9          1     9 asinc12_lab612.wmv ASD   asinc       no              0        1     1       1313
10         1    10  asinc9_lab879.wmv ASD   asinc       no              0        1     1       1460
11         1    11   asinc3_con13.wmv TD    asinc       no              0        2     1       2330
12         1    12   sinc11_con13.wmv TD    sinc        si              1        3     0       2003
13         1    13   sinc4_lab879.wmv ASD   sinc        si              1        5     1       2334
```

Thanks
Mauro

Comment: You'll need to add an indicator variable for each subject (if one is not already available) and then look at one of the many aggregation functions in R (one of which is called `aggregate`).

Comment: posting a small sample of the data would be very helpful

Comment: I think you left your comments as answers. You may want to change that.

Comment: The answers section is not for your general thoughts/philosophical discssuions, you can use the comments section for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing on Ananda Mahto's suggestion.
Here is a simple example of the aggregate function:

```
> y
     [,1]     [,2] [,3]
[1,] 417.0761 3.656920    1
[2,] 549.2227 1.279305    1
[3,] 617.8346 2.676573    2
[4,] 445.3850 3.646215    2
[5,] 451.8529 4.337643    1
[6,] 391.7912 3.995142    2


# get mean and median by group (column 3 of y)
y.mean   <- aggregate(y[,1:2], by=list(y[,3]), mean)
y.median <- aggregate(y[,1:2], by=list(y[,3]), median)

# merge y.mean and median by group, and label with suffix
y.summary <- merge(y.mean, y.median,by='Group.1', suffixes=c('mean','median'))

# print out result
print(summary)

  Group.1   V1mean   V2mean V1median V2median
1       1 472.7172 3.091289 451.8529 3.656920
2       2 485.0036 3.439310 445.3850 3.646215
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I do not know how your data frame looks like, I created a simple sample data. Here is another approach using `dplyr`.

```
#sample data frame
id <- rep(1:10, each = 40)
rt <- runif(400, 0.1, 1.5)
rt2 <- runif(400, 0.1,1.7)
foo <- data.frame(id, rt, rt2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

foo %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(mean = mean(., na.rm = TRUE),
                   median = median(., na.rm = TRUE)))

#   id   rt_mean  rt2_mean rt_median rt2_median
#1   1 0.7217723 0.8612916 0.6722035  0.8950618
#2   2 0.7374311 0.8930941 0.6821156  0.8767759
#3   3 0.8419620 0.7738735 0.8913319  0.7270914
#4   4 0.8388703 1.0013907 0.7652657  1.1188743
#5   5 0.8680372 0.8122654 0.8801511  0.6933033
#6   6 0.8141279 0.9359209 0.9551427  0.9362919
#7   7 0.8091938 0.8359638 0.8469513  0.7844926
#8   8 0.7366915 0.7522470 0.7680704  0.6833661
#9   9 0.7470820 0.7840083 0.6487139  0.7460022
#10 10 0.7998107 0.6379467 0.8203582  0.5896608
```

Update: Seeing what you were trying to do with `aggregate()` in your comment, you could do something like this with `dplyr`. You get mean and median of Risposta and RT in this case.

```
mydf %>%
    filter(Synchrony == "si") %>% # subset data with si only
    group_by(Subject) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(mean = mean(., na.rm = TRUE),
                        median = median(., na.rm = TRUE)),
                        Risposta, RT)

#  I am missing the last row of the data here. So, the results should be
#  slightly different with the full data set.
#  Subject Risposta_mean RT_mean Risposta_median RT_median
#1       1             4  1710.5               4    1710.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using data.table with @jazzurro sample data:

```
> library(data.table)
> foodt = data.table(foo)
> foodt[,list(mean.rt=mean(rt), median.rt=median(rt), mean.rt2=mean(rt2), median.rt2=median(rt2)),by=id]
    id   mean.rt median.rt  mean.rt2 median.rt2
 1:  1 0.8370809 0.7547919 0.8533929  0.8363765
 2:  2 0.8050453 0.8131681 0.9579030  1.0284944
 3:  3 0.8221798 0.8210501 0.9458442  1.0073267
 4:  4 0.8491232 0.8463559 0.9728266  0.9574839
 5:  5 0.7617457 0.7176411 0.9349860  0.9857195
 6:  6 0.5956108 0.4745952 0.9008883  0.9105738
 7:  7 0.8396380 0.7679036 0.8994247  0.9631958
 8:  8 0.7882674 0.7532493 0.8935340  0.8600171
 9:  9 0.8827633 0.9542983 0.9341739  0.8908895
10: 10 0.7579038 0.7140594 0.9200357  0.8963950
```

Results are coming different from @jazzurro results since set.seed is not used.

Answer (score 1):

If there are a lot of columns to `aggregate`, another option in `data.table` would be:

```
 library(data.table) # using data.table_1.9.5, though it should work with earlier versions

 nm1 <- c("Risposta", "RT") # subset of `colnames` of `mydf` from which `mean`, `median` etc are calculated.
```

If you need the `mean`, `median` for the above columns for a subset of dataset ie. `mydf$Synchrony=='si'`, then

```
 setDT(mydf)[Synchrony=='si', as.list(unlist(lapply(.SD, function(x)
            list(mean=mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), median=median(x, na.rm=TRUE))))),
                           by=Subject,.SDcols=nm1] 

 #   Subject Risposta.mean Risposta.median  RT.mean RT.median
#1:       1      4.333333               5 1918.333      2003
```

In the above code, `setDT(mydf)`, converts `data.frame` object to `data.table`.  Then used logical indicator `Synchrony=='si'` to apply the function only for those rows that are `TRUE` for the condition.  `.SD` means `S`ubset of `D`ata.table.  When we specify `.SDcols`, and we use `lapply(.SD,..)`, it is creating a list with the columns specified in `nm1` or `.SDcols=nm1`.  If you have multiple functions, use `list` to join it i.e. `list(mean=mean(x,na.rm=TRUE), median=median(x,na.rm=TRUE))` and lastly do `unlist(lapply(..`, `as.list(` to get the result in the wide format.

#### data

```
mydf <-  structure(list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Trial = 8:13, 
File = c("sinc2_lab579.wmv", "asinc12_lab612.wmv", "asinc9_lab879.wmv", 
"asinc3_con13.wmv", "sinc11_con13.wmv", "sinc4_lab879.wmv"
), Int = c("ASD", "ASD", "ASD", "TD", "TD", "ASD"), Target = c("sinc", 
"asinc", "asinc", "asinc", "sinc", "sinc"), Synchrony = c("si", 
"no", "no", "no", "si", "si"), corr_ans = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L), Risposta = c(5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L), ACC = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), RT = c(1418L, 1313L, 1460L, 2330L, 2003L, 
2334L)), .Names = c("Subject", "Trial", "File", "Int", "Target", 
"Synchrony", "corr_ans", "Risposta", "ACC", "RT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13"))
```